# Error transforming XML AJAX response in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt, internet-explorer-10

In Internet Explorer 10 only, I get an error transforming XML returned from an AJAX response:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode'

Here is my code:

```js
function transformXML(xmlUrl, xsl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: xmlUrl,
        success: function (xml, status, xhr) {
            // cross-browser logic omitted for simplicity
            xml.transformNode(xsl);
        },
        dataType: 'xml'
    });
}
```

This works in IE7 - IE9.  What's wrong with IE10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because, [as of IE 10, `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML` returns a "native XML document" by default instead of an MSXML document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx).

You can coerce the `XMLHttpRequest` object to return an MSXML object instead by setting the `responseType` property to `"msxml-document"`.  Unfortunately, this breaks in Google Chrome, so you need to wrap it in a try/catch.

Assign it during jQuery's `beforeSend` function:

```js
function transformXML(xmlUrl, xsl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: xmlUrl,
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            try { xhr.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch(err){}
        },
        success: function (xml, status, xhr) {
            // cross-browser logic omitted for simplicity
            xml.transformNode(xsl);
        },
        dataType: 'xml'
    });
}
```

**Note:**  Don't try to use the `xhrFields` setting - jQuery does not handle the error thrown by Chrome (and other browsers?) when attempting to set the `responseType` to an invalid value.  That needs to be wrapped in a try/catch, and the best way to do that is in the `beforeSend` function.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I had a similar issue, which got completly solved after adding your beforeSend bit and when I added `dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",` to the $ajax call as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the xhr.responseType = "msxml-document" put into beforeSend event seems not to work for me; I still receive a "native XML document" instead of an "MSXML" document (ie 10, jquery 1.9.1). Happens to others?

Answer (score 1):

@mauris:
It's broken in jquery 1.9.1 because they are ignoring responseXML and creating a new DOM from responseText, which doesn't work.

I modified jquery 1.9.1 (around line 8570 just after it copies responseText)

```
try
{
  var xml = xhr.responseXML;
  if (xml && xml.documentElement)
    responses.xml = xml;
} catch (_) { }
```

which fixes that.  The code is the same as what it did in 1.8.3 wrapped in a try/catch for safety.